# Delay while consuming messages from JMS Topic

Tags: java, jms, messaging

I have a topic with durable subscribers.  I can publish and consume the messages, however I see there is some delay while reading the messages from topic.

I am not able read the messages in a single call. I need to call the method multiple times to read the messages. Am I missing anything?

```
    private void publishMessage() {
        TopicConnection topicConnection = null;
        TopicSession topicSession = null;
        TopicPublisher topicPublisher = null;
        try {
          topicConnection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
          topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          Topic topicName= topicSession.createTopic(topicName);
          topicPublisher = topicSession.createPublisher(topicName);
          ObjectMessage message = topicSession.createObjectMessage(customObject)
          message.setStringProperty("user", userProperty);
          topicPublisher.publish(message, DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, timeToLive);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Error Sending UMessage", e);
        } finally {
          closeConnections(null, topicPublisher, topicSession, topicConnection);
        }
    }

public void consumeMessages(String userId, int maxResults) {
    TopicConnection topicConnection = null;
    TopicSession topicSession = null;
    TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber = null;

    try {
      topicConnection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection("guest","guest");
      topicConnection.setClientID("topic");
      topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Topic topicName= topicSession.createTopic(topicName);
      topicSubscriber = topicSession.createDurableSubscriber(topicName, "subscriptionname", String.format("user = '%s'", userName), false);
      topicConnection.start();
      Message msg = null;

      do {
        msg = topicSubscriber.receiveNoWait();
        if (msg instanceof ObjectMessage) {
          ObjectMessage om = (ObjectMessage) msg;
         else {
            log.error(String.format(" %s", om.getObject().getClass().getSimpleName()));
          }
        } else if (msg != null) {
          log.error(String.format("e %s", msg.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        }
      } while (msg != null && out.size() <= maxResults);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error retrieving User Messages", e);
    } finally {
      closeConnections(topicSubscriber, null, topicSession, topicConnection);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling receiveNoWait() which will retrieve one message at a time.  What normally happens, depending on your JMS provider, is that the JMS client will retrieve a number of messages at once and cache them on the client side to reduce network latency.  When you call receive it is then taking the message from this cache and giving it to you.

If you are seeing minute long delays there is either something wrong with how you are putting these messages onto the topic or you are blocking your message receive while you process each message.  If you would like to not block your message receipt while processing take a look at implementing the `MessageListener` interface instead of the using the receive methods or you can take the messages from your receive method and process them on a thread pool asynchronously.

When you create the consumer you can add the listener like so:

```
MessageListener listener = new MyListener();
consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
```

Then create a class to handle the messages or implement the interface in your existing consumer class:

```
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
  public void onMessage(Message message)
  {
     TextMessage text = (TextMessage) message;

     System.out.println("Message: " + text.getText());
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve all the available messages for a subscriber.That is the reason am looping for specified number of messages. It is reading all the messages, but not immediately after publishing, It takes 5-6 min(sometimes eve more). I observed one weird behavior if I run my jboss on debug mode and if I have some break points it is reading the messages immediately. However if a run in normal mode it is taking some time to read.

Comment: Since you mentioned JBoss I'm assuming you are using JBoss Messaging inside of the application server as your JMS provider?

Comment: Yes you right. I am using JMS server provided by JBOSS. Am I missing any configs ?

Comment: I think your code is fine, but I think your expectations of how receive works are incorrect.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs gregory. Actually I don't want to use MessageListener or MDBs,because if I use a listener the message would be consumed as soon as it is published on to topic. I want to read all the messages for particular subscriber in one shot.(By using message selector). Its like publishing message to a subscriber and read all the message later some point.